# iOS 13.5.1 and UIButton gradients

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an extension to UIButton that I use to style the buttons. This code has served me well for many years and recently my phone upgraded to 13.5.1 and this code isn't working great. The gradient in normal state is not visible anymore. Not sure exactly which iOS version broken this but would be definately >iOS 13. Was working before that. I thought it might be to do with dark mode so I put a User Interface Style = Light in my plist, this seems to have no effect. Even putting it to dark seems to make no different to the look of my UI.

What might be happening here and whats the conflict with the latest iOS?

```
#import "UIButton+CompletionBlocks.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

#define DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH 0.5f

@interface UIButton (CompletionBlocksPrivate)

@property (nonatomic) CAGradientLayer *normalLayer;
@property (nonatomic) CAGradientLayer *highlightedLayer;
@property (nonatomic) CAGradientLayer *selectedLayer;
@property (nonatomic) CAGradientLayer *selectedHighlightedLayer;
@property (nonatomic) CAGradientLayer *currentActiveLayer;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *borderColor;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *selectedBorderColor;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *textColor;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *selectedTextColor;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL styled;

@end

@implementation UIButton (CompletionBlocksPrivate)

void *_normalLayer;
void *_highlightedLayer;
void *_selectedLayer;
void *_selectedHighlightedLayer;
void *_currentActiveLayer;
void *_borderColor;
void *_selectedBorderColor;
void *_textColor;
void *_selectedTextColor;
void *_styled;


-(CAGradientLayer *) normalLayer {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_normalLayer);
}

-(void) setNormalLayer:(CAGradientLayer *)normalLayer {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &_normalLayer, normalLayer, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(CAGradientLayer *) highlightedLayer {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_highlightedLayer);
}

-(void) setHighlightedLayer:(CAGradientLayer *)highlightedLayer {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &_highlightedLayer, highlightedLayer, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(CAGradientLayer *) selectedLayer {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_selectedLayer);
}

-(void) setSelectedLayer:(CAGradientLayer *)selectedLayer {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &_selectedLayer, selectedLayer, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(CAGradientLayer *) selectedHighlightedLayer {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_selectedHighlightedLayer);
}

-(void) setSelectedHighlightedLayer:(CAGradientLayer *)selectedHighlightedLayer {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &_selectedHighlightedLayer, selectedHighlightedLayer, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(CAGradientLayer *) currentActiveLayer {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_currentActiveLayer);
}

-(void) setCurrentActiveLayer:(CAGradientLayer *)currentActiveLayer {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &_currentActiveLayer, currentActiveLayer, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(UIColor *) borderColor {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_borderColor);
}

-(void) setBorderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &_borderColor, borderColor, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(UIColor *) selectedBorderColor {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_selectedBorderColor);
}

-(void) setSelectedBorderColor:(UIColor *)selectedBorderColor {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &_selectedBorderColor, selectedBorderColor, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(UIColor *) textColor {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_textColor);
}

-(void) setTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &_textColor, textColor, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(UIColor *) selectedTextColor {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_selectedTextColor);
}

-(void) setSelectedTextColor:(UIColor *)selectedTextColor {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &_selectedTextColor, selectedTextColor, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(BOOL) styled {
    NSNumber *number = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_styled);
    return number.boolValue;
}

-(void) setStyled:(BOOL)styled {
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithBool:styled];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &_styled, number, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end

@implementation UIButton (CompletionBlocks)

- (UIButtonCompletionBlock )clickListener {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(clickListener));
}

- (void)setClickListener:(UIButtonCompletionBlock)completion{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(clickListener), completion, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void) buttonClicked {
    self.clickListener(self);
}

-(void) styleAsWhiteButton_GreenWhenSelected {
    UIColor *normalGradientStart = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xfe/255.0f green:0xfe/255.0f blue:0xfe/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *normalGradientEnd = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xf2/255.0f green:0xf2/255.0f blue:0xf2/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *highlightedGradientStart = normalGradientEnd;
    UIColor *highlightedGradientEnd = normalGradientStart;
    UIColor *selectedGradientStart = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xa7/255.0f green:0xb7/255.0f blue:0x4e/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedGradientEnd = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x8f/255.0f green:0xa1/255.0f blue:0x40/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedHighlightedGradientStart = selectedGradientEnd;
    UIColor *selectedHighlightedGradientEnd = selectedGradientStart;
    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xcc/255.0f green:0xcc/255.0f blue:0xcc/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedBorderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x89/255.0f green:0x9b/255.0f blue:0x3a/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x56/255.0f green:0x56/255.0f blue:0x56/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xff/255.0f green:0xff/255.0f blue:0xff/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *disabledTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xbf/255.0f green:0xbf/255.0f blue:0xbf/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    [self setStyleWithTextColor:textColor selectedTextColor:selectedTextColor disabledTextColor:disabledTextColor gradientStartColor:normalGradientStart gradientEndColor:normalGradientEnd highlightedGradientStartColor:highlightedGradientStart highlightedGradientEndColor:highlightedGradientEnd selectedGradientStartColor:selectedGradientStart selectedGradientEndColor:selectedGradientEnd selectedHighlightedGradientStartColor:selectedHighlightedGradientStart selectedHighlightedGradientEndColor:selectedHighlightedGradientEnd borderColor:borderColor selectedBorderColor:selectedBorderColor];
}

-(void) styleAsFingerButton_NotRequired {
    UIColor *normalGradientStart = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xef/255.0f green:0xef/255.0f blue:0xef/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *normalGradientEnd = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xdf/255.0f green:0xdf/255.0f blue:0xdf/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *highlightedGradientStart = normalGradientEnd;
    UIColor *highlightedGradientEnd = normalGradientStart;
    UIColor *selectedGradientStart = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xe1/255.0f green:0x53/255.0f blue:0x26/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedGradientEnd = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xb4/255.0f green:0x43/255.0f blue:0x1e/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedHighlightedGradientStart = selectedGradientEnd;
    UIColor *selectedHighlightedGradientEnd = selectedGradientStart;
    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xd3/255.0f green:0xd3/255.0f blue:0xd3/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedBorderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xc3/255.0f green:0x49/255.0f blue:0x22/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x56/255.0f green:0x56/255.0f blue:0x56/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xff/255.0f green:0xff/255.0f blue:0xff/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *disabledTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xbf/255.0f green:0xbf/255.0f blue:0xbf/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    [self setStyleWithTextColor:textColor selectedTextColor:selectedTextColor disabledTextColor:disabledTextColor gradientStartColor:normalGradientStart gradientEndColor:normalGradientEnd highlightedGradientStartColor:highlightedGradientStart highlightedGradientEndColor:highlightedGradientEnd selectedGradientStartColor:selectedGradientStart selectedGradientEndColor:selectedGradientEnd selectedHighlightedGradientStartColor:selectedHighlightedGradientStart selectedHighlightedGradientEndColor:selectedHighlightedGradientEnd borderColor:borderColor selectedBorderColor:selectedBorderColor];
}

-(void) styleAsFingerButton_Required {
    UIColor *normalGradientStart = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xdf/255.0f green:0xd9/255.0f blue:0xb9/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *normalGradientEnd = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xd6/255.0f green:0xc5/255.0f blue:0x9b/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *highlightedGradientStart = normalGradientEnd;
    UIColor *highlightedGradientEnd = normalGradientStart;
    UIColor *selectedGradientStart = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xe1/255.0f green:0x53/255.0f blue:0x26/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedGradientEnd = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xb4/255.0f green:0x43/255.0f blue:0x1e/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedHighlightedGradientStart = selectedGradientEnd;
    UIColor *selectedHighlightedGradientEnd = selectedGradientStart;
    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xcd/255.0f green:0xbf/255.0f blue:0x9d/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedBorderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xc3/255.0f green:0x49/255.0f blue:0x22/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x56/255.0f green:0x56/255.0f blue:0x56/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *selectedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xff/255.0f green:0xff/255.0f blue:0xff/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *disabledTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xbf/255.0f green:0xbf/255.0f blue:0xbf/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    [self setStyleWithTextColor:textColor selectedTextColor:selectedTextColor disabledTextColor:disabledTextColor gradientStartColor:normalGradientStart gradientEndColor:normalGradientEnd highlightedGradientStartColor:highlightedGradientStart highlightedGradientEndColor:highlightedGradientEnd selectedGradientStartColor:selectedGradientStart selectedGradientEndColor:selectedGradientEnd selectedHighlightedGradientStartColor:selectedHighlightedGradientStart selectedHighlightedGradientEndColor:selectedHighlightedGradientEnd borderColor:borderColor selectedBorderColor:selectedBorderColor];
}

-(void) setStyleWithTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor selectedTextColor:(UIColor *)selectedTextColor disabledTextColor:(UIColor *)disabledTextColor gradientStartColor:(UIColor *)gradientStartColor gradientEndColor:(UIColor *)gradientEndColor highlightedGradientStartColor:(UIColor *)highlightedGradientStartColor highlightedGradientEndColor:(UIColor *)highlightedGradientEndColor selectedGradientStartColor:(UIColor *)selectedGradientStartColor selectedGradientEndColor:(UIColor *)selectedGradientEndColor selectedHighlightedGradientStartColor:(UIColor *)selectedHighlightedGradientStartColor selectedHighlightedGradientEndColor:(UIColor *)selectedHighlightedGradientEndColor borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor selectedBorderColor:(UIColor *)selectedBorderColor {

    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    self.borderColor = borderColor;
    self.selectedBorderColor = selectedBorderColor;
    self.textColor = textColor;
    self.selectedTextColor = selectedTextColor;

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
    self.layer.borderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;

    [self setTitleColor:disabledTextColor forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [self setTitleColor:selectedTextColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    // gradient
    self.normalLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    self.normalLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    self.normalLayer.colors = @[(id)gradientStartColor.CGColor,
                            (id)gradientEndColor.CGColor];
    self.normalLayer.locations = @[@0, @1.0];
    self.highlightedLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    self.highlightedLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    self.highlightedLayer.colors = @[(id)highlightedGradientStartColor.CGColor,
                                (id)highlightedGradientEndColor.CGColor];
    self.highlightedLayer.locations = @[@0, @1.0];
    self.selectedLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    self.selectedLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    self.selectedLayer.colors = @[(id)selectedGradientStartColor.CGColor,
                                (id)selectedGradientEndColor.CGColor];
    self.selectedLayer.locations = @[@0, @1.0];
    self.selectedHighlightedLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    self.selectedHighlightedLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    self.selectedHighlightedLayer.colors = @[(id)selectedHighlightedGradientStartColor.CGColor,
                                     (id)selectedHighlightedGradientEndColor.CGColor];
    self.selectedHighlightedLayer.locations = @[@0, @1.0];

    [self setSelected:self.selected]; // draw the button
    self.clipsToBounds  = YES;
    self.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];
}

-(void) buttonDown:(UIButton *)sender {
    if(self.selected) {
        [self makeLayerActive:self.selectedHighlightedLayer];
    } else {
        [self makeLayerActive:self.highlightedLayer];
    }
}

-(void) buttonUp:(UIButton *)sender {
    if(self.selected) {
        [self makeLayerActive:self.selectedLayer];
    } else {
        [self makeLayerActive:self.normalLayer];
    }
}

-(void) setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    [self buttonUp:self]; // just draw the button up
    if(selected) {
        self.layer.borderColor = self.selectedBorderColor.CGColor;
        [self setTitleColor:self.selectedTextColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setTitleColor:self.selectedTextColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        self.titleLabel.textColor = self.selectedTextColor;
    } else {
        self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.CGColor;
        [self setTitleColor:self.textColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setTitleColor:self.textColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        self.titleLabel.textColor = self.textColor;
    }
}

-(void) setBorderedSelected:(BOOL)borderedSelected {
    if(borderedSelected) {
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.5f;
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    } else {
        self.layer.borderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
    }
}

-(void) makeLayerActive:(CAGradientLayer *)layer {
    [self.currentActiveLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
    self.currentActiveLayer = layer;
}

@end
```

Comment: seems like it is not to do with the iOS version as someone with that version, the buttons are working fine. It has something to do with the binary built with the latest iOS 13.5 SDK. In worst case scenario, how can I build with the old SDK?

Comment: I have a hard time to understand what's the problem. Can you include your `UIButton+CompletionBlocks.h`? So one can copy & paste header & implementation and try it. Also can you include a screenshot of how it should look like, how it looks like (what's the problem) and how did you instantiate the button & what method you call from your category.

Comment: You can compile with an older Xcode.  When Apple makes potentially breaking changes, they usually keep the old behavior for apps compiled with older Xcodes.  If it breaks with a new one, you are expected to figure out the problem before you release an app built that way.  Some behavior changed -- you may want to run with different Xcodes to figure out which behavior is different.  Maybe self.selected now doesn't change until after your buttonUp: method is called, or something like that.

Comment: OK I figured out the reason, it is because in my category I am overriding UIButton's setSelected() method. Yes there is docs that overriding methods in categories is undocumented behaviour. All xcode compilers previously seemed to work in my favour, unfortunately the latest compiler doesn't and so my setSelected never gets called, only the UIButton one does. So I switched to swizzling the method instead of overriding and now all is good! Swizzling is explained here: https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/